# ideas/hacks for using javascript inside an iframe with remote content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I'm trying to throw together a proof of concept in rails where I want to put a remote sites content inside and iframe and then use jQuery to modify the content in the iframe. I know that I can't really do this because of cross site scripting protections and I also know it's not a great design; it's just a hack as a proof of concept. But, is there anyway to scrape the html from the remote site and pipe that into the iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set up a proxy page on your own server that reads the source and echos it to the destination? Alternatively, you could try disabling security on your demo browser. On Chrome/Windows, it's `chrome.exe --disable-web-security`.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer you can't do this.

However, you can try some crazy solution like download remote page using wget and then link file to the iframe. But then the page is not really in different domain.

BTW, you may want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage maybe it will be helpful in some cases for you.